# Google cloud endpoint RequestMessage with multiple fields resolution

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

Cloud endpoint ResponseMessage seem straightforward to me. If I have a response message class

```
class FoodieResponseMessage(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1)
  fav_food = messages.StringField(2)
  city = messages.StringField(3)
```

invoking it is as simple as

```
FoodieResponseMessage(name="A", fav_food="B", city="C")
```

But what of a `RequestMessage` with multiple fields? All I get from the service endpoint method is a `request` object. How do I know what field goes where?

```
class FoodieRequestMessage(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1)
  id = messages.StringField(2)
  sitting_table = messages.StringField(3)

 @endpoints.method(FoodieRequestMessage, FoodieResponseMessage)
 def process(self, request):
   name = request.name
   id = request.id
   table = request.sitting_table
```

How does the request match the field so that i don't end up getting a user's `sitting_table` when I do `request.name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods need to be members of an API class:

```
from protorpc import remote

class FoodieAPI(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(FoodieRequestMessage, FoodieResponseMessage)
  def process(self, request):
    # Handle request
```

Since `process` is a member of a `remote.Service` subclass, the actual handler which is created by

```
application = endpoints.api_server([FoodieApi])
```

knows how to turn JSON into the native message request class you have specified (`FoodieRequestMessage`) and also expects you to return an instance of the response class you have specified (`FoodieResponseMessage`) because it can convert that back to JSON as well.

For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> from protorpc import protojson
>>>
>>> payload = json.dumps({
>>>     'name': 'Dan', 
>>>     'fav_food': 'Mac and Cheese', 
>>>     'city': 'San Francisco'
>>> })
>>> message = protojson.decode_message(FoodieResponseMessage, payload)
>>> message
<FoodieResponseMessage
 name: u'Dan'
 fav_food: u'Mac and Cheese'
 city: u'San Francisco'>
```

so when your request payload is

```
{"city": "San Francisco", "fav_food": "Mac and Cheese", "name": "Dan"}
```

the `request` object in your method will have

```
>>> message.name
u'Dan'
>>> message.fav_food
u'Mac and Cheese'
>>> message.city
u'San Francisco'
```

Comment: So is my `FoodieRequestMessage` class good the way it is? I have seen people use all kind of stuff such as `messages.EnumField`. I thought those were somehow necessary to tell the `endpoints` api which queryparameter/pathparameter to set, say, `sitting_table` to.

Comment: It is fine as it is. You can use an `EnumField` if you have a use for enums, but this doesn't change how the fields are parsed.